# Where to register the Native Messaging Host in Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os, chrome-native-messaging

In [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) documentation there's the location for Windows, Mac OS and Linux.

I assumed Chrome OS would work the same as "standard" linux, but i couldnt get my app working ...

com.my_app.host.json (located in /etc/opt/chrome/native-messaging-hosts/)

```html
{
  "name": "com.my_app.host",
  "description": "My Host",
  "path": "/home/user/bfd93db2180e0d7645b1f4cce2d2c7ed9e0d835c/Downloads/host.sh",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://APP_ID/"
  ]
}
```

---

main.js

```js
var port = null;

var getKeys = function(obj) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var key in obj) {
    keys.push(key);
  }
  return keys;
}


function appendMessage(text) {
  document.getElementById('response').innerHTML += "<p>" + text + "</p>";
}

function updateUiState() {
  if (port) {
    document.getElementById('connect-button').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('input-text').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('send-message-button').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('connect-button').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('input-text').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('send-message-button').style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function sendNativeMessage() {
  message = {
    "text": document.getElementById('input-text').value
  };
  port.postMessage(message);
  appendMessage("Sent message: <b>" + JSON.stringify(message) + "</b>");
}

function onNativeMessage(message) {
  appendMessage("Received message: <b>" + JSON.stringify(message) + "</b>");
}

function onDisconnected() {
  appendMessage("Failed to connect: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
  port = null;
  updateUiState();
}

function connect() {
  var hostName = "com.my_app.host";
  appendMessage("Connecting to native messaging host <b>" + hostName + "</b>")
  port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
  port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
  port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
  updateUiState();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('connect-button').addEventListener(
    'click', connect);
  document.getElementById('send-message-button').addEventListener(
    'click', sendNativeMessage);
  updateUiState();
});

index.html
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src='./main.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id='connect-button'>Connect</button>
  <input id='input-text' type='text' />
  <button id='send-message-button'>Send</button>
  <div id='response'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

It just says:

Connecting to native messaging host com.my_app.host

Failed to connect: Specified native messaging host not found.

Also i cant enable logging as explained in the documentation because on Chrome OS you cant just open Chrome via a command.

Would be great if someone could help me :)

Basically i just want to create a little GUI for launching Crouton commands.

Comment: Looks like even the pros have problems with installing the messaging host in Chrome OS:
https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=5576

"** Binaries cannot be installed in Chrome OS"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome OS does not support third-party native messaging hosts. As of writing, only two native messaging hosts are supported. One for testing, and one for Chrome Remote Desktop (source: [native_message_host_chromeos.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/4d364160d6f31c5b0235530af822b5c04e3fe523/chrome/browser/extensions/api/messaging/native_message_host_chromeos.cc#153)).

On Chrome OS, logs are available at `/var/log/chrome/chrome` and `/var/log/ui/ui.LATEST`. There are other ways to read/toggle the log (see
https://dev.chromium.org/chromium-os/how-tos-and-troubleshooting/building-chromium-browser#TOC-Debugging and
https://github.com/ds-hwang/wiki/wiki/Build-Chromium-for-Chromium-OS-and-Deploy-to-real-device#log).

But the absence of built-in support for native messaging hosts does not mean that you cannot achieve what you want. Start a local HTTP server in Crouton, and communicate between the Chrome extension / app and the HTTP server via the standard Web APIs (`XMLHttpRequest`, `fetch`, `WebSocket`, ...). On the server (running in Crouton), you can do whatever you want (e.g. starting local scripts).
Make sure that the server implements proper authentication (to prevent unauthorized access by other web sites or extensions) (and preferably bind to a local address only to make the server inaccessible over network).

Comment: Are there any updates regarding this issue? Google decided to discontinue Chrome Apps even on Chrome OS and there is an option to install Linux (Beta) on Chromebooks that allows you to run native Linux apps. However it seems that Linux runs in VM and doesn't detect the installed Native Message Host.

Comment: Does anyone if that still apply? I see code has changed a lot.